# What call is exactly blocking or sleeping the main thread in a typical Swing example code?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I've seen a lot of Swing app setups, and I always wonder what exactly makes them blocking until the close button is pressed, like in the official:

[Oracle Swing HelloWorld](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java)

I mean, if `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is async, where is the main thread blocking?

Comment: The main thread is not blocking. Using swing starts another thread: the event dispatch thread. The JVM only stops when *all* non-daemon threads have stopped. Not just the main thread.

Comment: Nice, now I understand what that setDaemon thing did mean in Thread :)

Comment: Anyway, where is this daemon thread exactly called?

Comment: It is not a daemon thread. Otherwise the JVM would stop. AFAIK, it is started as soon as invokeLater is called, or a top-level component is made visible. But I might be wrong here.

Comment: I suggest checking out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317766/when-is-the-swing-ui-thread-created/26319685#26319685) to find out how/when the EDT is created

Answer (score 0):

The main thread isn't blocked or sleeping at all. It has exited.

Comment: Could you elaborate bit further please, in the vein as some comments (3 or 4 lines), so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't see how, or why. What part of 'it has exiited' don't you understand?

Comment: I don't know, JB Nizet comments are far more detaled explanation, I felt sorry to accept an answer while those comments are more valuable for the community